# Cannot remove workspace from being recommended even after deleting it in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I deleted the workspace in Finder (mac).
In Eclipse, in ;General -> startup and shutdown -> workspaces; removed it from recent workspaces.
I created a new workspace i want to use.

But whenever i startup eclipse it shows only the old deleted workspace as the recommended workspace to be opened. (old workspace when i startup eclipse pictured here)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szMyx.png

I tried providing my new workspace when it asks what workspace you want to open in the opening dialogue box and checking the 'use this as the default and do not ask again' ckeckbox, but it keeps asking if i want to open the old deleted workspace.

I also tried recursively deleting some files related to the workspace. This was a few weeks back.

Any idea how to stop a deleted workspace from being suggested over and over again in the opening dialogue box and make it suggest the newly created workspace?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of eclipse?

Comment: Tried it just now. provided new workspace in the startup dialogue, cleared cache in remote systems, removed workspace from recent workspaces, deleted in finder,  and restarted eclipse. It worked when i immediately booted up eclipse after doing this (showed new workspace with code window open), but when doing this after a few mins or after restarting the mac, it goes back to old behavior.

Comment: I dont remember installing oomph, nothing comes up in spotlight either. [][][]
tried cleaning, didnt work
:
Dred95-Laptop:MacOS shivganesh$ pwd []
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS []
Dred95-Laptop:MacOS shivganesh$ eclipse -clean -refresh []
-bash: eclipse: command not found [][][][]

tried ./eclipse -clean -> this opened eclipse with same behaviour as before

Comment: It isn't a good idea to delete a workspace before switching to a new one! If you want switch the workspace permanently, you have to use File > Switch workspace > other. If this doesn't work you have to reset eclipse by deleting  the directory .eclipse in your home directory. But this should be your last fallback!

Comment: The current workspace, the _do not ask again_ option and the list of recently used workpaces are stored in the configuration area, not in the workspace itself. Maybe you run Eclipse with a user (e.g. as admin) with different file permissions than you currently have before, so the created configuration files can not be changed now. Did you? Which macOS and Eclipse version do you have? Did you installed Eclipse via the Eclipse Installer or directly as *.dmg file?

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz i created a new workspace before trying to delete the old one. i tried switching workspace through File > Switch workspace > other, this just opens a new window with selected workspace, doesn't seem to solve the startup problem.

Comment: @howlger i only have one user configured on my mac. macOS: 10.14.6 (18G9323), eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

I am using this version because it was recommended by the instructor in a course i am taking.

Comment: Eclipse Mars is 16 releases and more than 5 years behind, much older than macOS 10.14. It is recommended to use the latest Eclipse version since there are no long-term support versions. Your instructor is clearly wrong in this point. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).